# How to use Rabbitmq to communicate with SSL?

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq

I installed rabbitmq on Ubuntu and would like to communicate with ssl. There is no `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf` file, what should I write to the file when I create it myself? What are the operation steps?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to follow the relevant docs [TLS Support](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html)

Answer (score 0):

thanks, I created the rabbitmq.conf file in the / etc / rabbitmq directory. I used https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/master/docs/rabbitmq.conf.example inside the file. I wrote the certificates I created with TLS-GEN but failed when I restarted them. Error message:

● rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ broker
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-10-25 06:51:01 PDT; 6s ago
  Process: 73072 ExecStart=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server (code=exited, status=64)
 Main PID: 73072 (code=exited, status=64)

Oct 25 06:51:01 ubuntu systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 25 06:51:01 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start RabbitMQ broker.

Inside the RabbitMQ.conf file

listeners.tcp.local    = 127.0.0.1:5672

listeners.ssl.default = 5671

ssl_options.verify = verify_peer

ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert = false

ssl_options.cacertfile= /home/ekrem/tls-gen/basic/result/ca_certificate.pem

ssl_options.certfile= /home/ekrem/tls-gen/basic/result/server_certificate.pem

ssl_options.keyfile= /home/ekrem/tls-gen/basic/result/server_key.pem